# Extract elements from html using javascript

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Suppose I have a webpage on the web, this page has many elements with ids. How do I fetch these elements using javascript?
 I've used this chunk with jQuery:

```
    $.get(websiteUrl, {}, function(results){
    //alert(results); // will show the HTML from anotherPage.html
    console.log($(results).find("bookId").html()); // show "bookId" div in results
    });
```

But I get error:

```
 XMLHttpRequest cannot load; Origin http://127.0.0.1:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Actually, I'm trying to fetch some data from webpage in Phonegap app on Android.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Which browser are you testing it with? And did you try with your webpage's live version? Google Chrome won't let you send AJAX requests to your localhost for some reason.

Comment: Yeap, I was testing in Chrome. Actually, I need only those elements from webpage into my Phonegap app. Is there any way to fetch them without extra server-side logic? Why on WP7 Silverlight I can simply fetch images or text from HTML and on Phonegap no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers adhere to a strict same-origin policy. Meaning you can't make Ajax requests to a different server. While you can bypass it, it's not practical to do with every client.

Your best bet would be to invoke a server-side script to fetch it for you, and return the results to JavaScript.

Comment: You mean I cannot directly load content of a webpage to a Phonegap app? Actually I need only some images and text which sits on this site. Is there any javascript way to fetch those elements?

Comment: @RomanTolmachev: JavaScript is the wrong tool for the job. Don't hammer a nail with a shovel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jsonp to do cross-domain ajax calls, though you don't get error or timeout callbacks.  jsonp is natively supported by jQuery.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  The theory is you add a script tag to the page with a carefully formed url which includes the name of a callback function.  The server then processes the ajax "request", and returns the answer as a single parameter tp your callback function.

Comment: The problem is that I don't manage that server. It's not my website.

Comment: Then you must proxy the AJAX calls through the website you do control.